# How to convert pd.grouper series to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a code like this:

```
y1 = data.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='15d')])['ext price'].mean()
y=pd.DataFrame(y1)
y.head()
```

And the output is:

```
                                    ext price
name        datetime    
Barton LLC  2014-01-01 07:21:51     3380.91
            2014-01-16 07:21:51     399.5228571
            2014-01-31 07:21:51     1666.523333
            2014-02-15 07:21:51     1804.615
            2014-03-02 07:21:51     1171.176667
```

I want to get this output as DataFrame as like below:

```
    name        datetime                ext price
0   Barton LLC  2014-01-01 07:21:51     3380.91
1   Barton LLC  2014-01-16 07:21:51     399.5228571
2   Barton LLC  2014-01-31 07:21:51     1666.523333
3   Barton LLC  2014-02-15 07:21:51     1804.615
4   Barton LLC  2014-03-02 07:21:51     1171.176667
```

Comment: @Dev: Thank you for your suggestion. I will follow next time.

Comment: `y.reset_index()`

Comment: @U9-Forward : Thank you so much. Solved.

Comment: @KindDAnonymous I'll answer, then you can accept

Comment: heaven't saw it yet :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reset_index`:

```
print(y.reset_index())
```

`reset_index` just makes new index and makes old level as columns, and makes data-frame normal.

Output:

```
    name        datetime                ext price
0   Barton LLC  2014-01-01 07:21:51     3380.91
1   Barton LLC  2014-01-16 07:21:51     399.5228571
2   Barton LLC  2014-01-31 07:21:51     1666.523333
3   Barton LLC  2014-02-15 07:21:51     1804.615
4   Barton LLC  2014-03-02 07:21:51     1171.176667
```